# Cannot start new podcast, on buzzsprout via api, 400 how to fix?

Tags: python

My audio for podcast and art for it on google drive, in doc says to make like this, but it returns 400 error

```
import requests


podcast_file = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0IDXVotyHKEGSbBWUxEoDvaJQRsWCJO"


headers = {
    
    'Authorization': 'Token here my token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}


new_episode = {
    "title":"Too many or too few?",
    "description":"",
    "summary":"",
    "artist":"Muffin Man",
    "tags":"",
    "duration":23462,
    "guid":"Buzzsprout788880",
    "episode_number":1,
    "season_number":1,
    "explicit":False,
    "private":False,
    "email_user_after_audio_processed": False,
    "audio_url": podcast_file,
    "artwork_url": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xoNKAbTYX8GjVg0ZB_ekFUl8ljQICMZv"
}


url = 'https://www.buzzsprout.com/api/episodes.json'

req = requests.post(url, data=new_episode, headers=headers)

print(req.text)
print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: Does `req.text` have anything useful?

Comment: no just empty space

Comment: Pretty dump created api, https://www.buzzsprout.com/api/userid/episodes.json?api_token={token} but it not upload audio and artwork, also no needed to use headers